# how to use select only between dates (sql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

```
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
$propuser = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT propiedades.pnombre FROM propiedades INNER JOIN arriendos ON propiedades.pid=arriendos.propiedad WHERE arrendador='$codigo'");
```

the database have fields with dates like start: 2015-01-18 end 2015-06-18

How can i specify to search only if the fields are within range?
thank you!

edit: the main goal is to display the info if today is between start and end date.

Comment: You can say something like `some_date BETWEEN start AND end` which is equivalent to `some_date >= start AND some_date <= end`. You might have to be careful with time components but beyond that you haven't really defined what you my by "within range" and what you're checking.

Comment: Good Question, look at my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BETWEEN` is clean and understandable:

example on the `WHERE` clause

`WHERE propiedades BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2015-01-18', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND TO_DATE ('2015-06-18', 'yyyy/mm/dd')`

`TO_DATE` will convert into a proper format for your db.

Cheers.